# How to sum data of two different columns in SQL

Tags: sql

How can I update sum of data from different columns from 1 table to a different column in the same table?

Below is the example:

```
Name     Jan_Sales Feb_Sales March_Sales  Total_Sales
Cathey   345         450      530            ?
Susan    456         280      430            ?
Jason    346         590      567            ?
Chris    478         344      345            ?
```

I want to update column Total_Sales by summing Jan, Feb, Mar sales.. For e.g 1325(345+450+530) in total_sales for Cathey.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
update yourtable
set total_sales = jan_sales + feb_sales + march_sales
```

Answer (score 1):

This may work :

```
UPDATE
    table_name 
SET 
    Total_Sales = Jan_Sales + Feb_Sales + March_Sales
WHERE 1 = 1;
```

where 1=1 is to prevent mysql to warn that you are performing an UPDATE without WHERE clause